# Need help to add a width transition on my navbar buttons

Tags: html, css, button, navbar

I would be glad if anyone could tell me a way to add a width transition to the foldable buttons on my navbar :)

**HTML**

```html
<header>
    <h1 class="brand">Brand Name</h1>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="active" color="red">
                    <span class="navbar-icon">
                        <i data-feather="home"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="navbar-text">Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" color="blue">
                    <span class="navbar-icon">
                        <i data-feather="globe"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="navbar-text">Network</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" color="yellow">
                    <span class="navbar-icon">
                        <i data-feather="user"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="navbar-text">Profile</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```css
.navbar ul a {
    display: flex;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5px;
}

.navbar ul a .navbar-text {
    display: none;
}

.navbar ul a.active {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.navbar ul a.active .navbar-text {
    display: block;
}
```

The first thing I tried was using the `transition: width .2s;` to the `<a>` tag, but it didn't work out. Is it because the transition affects the changes exclusively made to the width property?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to transiton the width of the anchor tag you need to set the initial and final value

try this:
Initial size ->

```
.navbar ul a {
    width: 100px;
    transition: width 0.2s; /* Add transition to the width property */
}
```

active/ final size ->

```
.navbar ul a.active {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    width: 120px; 
}
```